# Why is my for loop returning only 1 object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, victory-charts, victory-native

I'm trying to convert the array and put "Day" in front of every month I have in my objects list, so I can use it to create a chart on React Native with Victory Native.

Here's my array:

`const months = ["08/31/2022", "09/01/2022", "08/31/2022", "08/31/2022", "08/31/2022", "08/31/2022"]`

And I need my final input to be:

`{"Day": "08/31/2022"},{"Day": "09/01/2022"}, {"Day": "08/31/2022"}, {"Day": "08/31/2022"}, {"Day": "08/31/2022"}, {"Day": "08/31/2022"}`

Here's my code:

```
var hash = {};
for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++)
  hash['Day'] = months[i];
console.log(hash)
```

My current output is:
 `{"Day": "08/31/2022"}`

As you can see it just prints out 1 object.

Any help will be much appreciated from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: TL;DR for the duplicate... `const hash = months.map((Day) => ({ Day }))`

Comment: That worked, thanks Phil, you;re an angel